# Delete rows from table which does not exists in other table by picking eligible records only

Tags: oracle, join, not-exists

I am using Oracle. i need to delete the rows from One table which does not exists in other table by joining it with table having only eligible ID.
I am sorry i am not sure how to explain it better. Below is an example. ID + SUB_ID is PK

```
Final_table - 
ID SUB_ID  Name
1  1       Football
1  2       Cricket
1  3       Formula1
1  4       Tennis
2  1       Hockey
2  2       Archery
2  3       Badminton
3  1       Basketball
3  2       Dodgeball 

Latest_Table
ID SUB_ID  Name
1  1       Football
1  2       Cricket
1  3       Formula1
2  1       Hockey
2  2       Archery
3  1       Basketball

Sample_Table
ID
1
3
```

From above example, i joined Latest_table with Sample_Table on ID column and it gave me ID (1,3). Now based on these IDs which are eligible, i want to delete the rows from Final_Table which are not present in Latest_Table. I don't want it to delete anything for ID=2 as it is not eligible.
I have written below code, but it is deleting everything from FINAL_TABLE which is not present in Latest_table.

```
Delete from FINAL_TABLE FT
where not exists 
(select 1 from 
Latest_table LT, Sample_table ST
where LT.ID = ST.ID
and LT.ID = FT.ID
and LT.SUB_ID = FT.SUB_ID);
```

Thank you for your help.

Edited-
desired result in Final_Table should look like

```
Final_table - 
ID SUB_ID  Name
1  1       Football
1  2       Cricket
1  3       Formula1
2  1       Hockey
2  2       Archery
2  3       Badminton
3  1       Basketball
```

Comment: sample_table and Latest_table will not have any change in data. Only rows from final_table needs to be deleted. I have edited my question with Desired output data. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I misread your query originally. I have changed my answer to remove the join to Sample_Table in the first condition.

```
Delete from FINAL_TABLE FT
where not exists 
(select 1 from 
Latest_table LT
where LT.ID = FT.ID
and LT.NAME = FT.NAME
and LT.SUB_ID = FT.SUB_ID)
AND FT.id IN
(
 SELECT id FROM Sample_Table
)
```

This will only delete from Final_Table if the id appears in Sample_Table and the record (all 3 columns) does not appear in the Latest_table.

An alternative way of writing this is

```
Delete from FINAL_TABLE FT
where 
  (FT.ID, FT.SUB_ID, FT.NAME) NOT IN
   (SELECT LT.ID, LT.SUB_ID, LT.NAME FROM Latest_table LT)
 AND FT.ID IN
  (SELECT ST.id FROM Sample_Table ST)
```